# can I run multiple def in one time

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web, webdriver

I want to run multiple def simultaneously like this

method_files.py

```
def one() :
    print("hi")

def two() :
    print("hi2")

def three() :
    print("hi3")
```

main.py:

```
from one import one

from two import two

from three import three

one()
two()
three()
```

I want to run these commands once:

```
one()
two()
three()
```

can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to run them?

Comment: Are these functions all in the same file? Your code snippet looks like they are, but the imports suggest otherwise

Comment: No, each one in a separate file

Comment: No I haven't tried it but it's just an example I'm actually going to put a long scritp instead of each one.

Comment: Looks like OP was looking for how to run these methods concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use threading

```
import threading

def function_1():
   print("1")

def function_2():
   print("2")

Thread1 = threading.Thread(target=function_1)
Thread2 = threading.Thread(target=function_2)

Thread1.start()
Thread1.start()
Thread1.join()
Thread2.join()
```

or you can use multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process

proccess1 = Process(target=function_1)
proccess2 = Process(target=function_2)

proccess1.start()
proccess2.start()

proccess1.join()
proccess2.join()
```